# Is there a way in iOS to block the camera while my app is running even if it is in the background?

Tags: ios, swift

I need to block the usage of the camera while my app is running, even in the background. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Please provide clarity and detailed information, such as code that you tried in order to solve the problem, doing so you have a higher chance to get answered

Comment: No, there is not

Comment: @GooDeeJAY Is a yes or no question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no im afraid thats not in your apps 'area of authority'
each app on ios runs sandboxed and you cant influence other apps